# is there any way to put sum value of one input into another input in same form in reactjs and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

> here is my react code for storing in state

i am trying to create a payroll field in which when i click on annual and submit the value into input then automatically another input field like basic and hra should get value according to formula e.g.=>  monthly = annual / 12 and basic = (monthly/100)*50

```
const PayrollHr = () => {
// 1. here i am using hook to store data
const [payroll, setPayroll] = useState({
    annual: '',
    monthly: '',
    basic: '',
    hra: '',
    fixedAllowance: '',
    variableAllowance: '',
    employerShare: '',
    statutoryBonus: ''
});
```

```
    const addPayroll = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        // let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        // let email = decoded.email;
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/hr/payroll', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                annual: payroll.annual,
                monthly: payroll.annual / 12,
                basic: payroll.basic,
                hra: payroll.hra,
                fixedAllowance: payroll.fixedAllowance,
                variableAllowance: payroll.variableAllowance,
                employerShare: payroll.employerShare,
                statutoryBonus: payroll.statutoryBonus,
                // email: email
            })
        })
            const data = await response.json();
        console.log(" payroll", data);
        
    }
```

> here is my react code for storing in state

```
    >here is my input field
    >in input field i want to do some math operatios like ( 50% of salary = basic 
salary)

 return (
    <div className='payroll_main'>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addPayroll}>
                <div className='form-group' >
    /// here i m trying to do some math operations like 50% of annual is basic salary
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' id='annual'
                        onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, annual: e.target.value })}
                        placeholder='Annual' />
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' id='monthly'
                        onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll.annual / 12, monthly: e.target.value })}
                        value={payroll.monthly}
                        placeholder='Monthly' />
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' id='basic'
                        onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, basic: e.target.value })}
                        // value={(payroll.monthly / 100) * 50}
                        placeholder='Basic' />
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' id='hra'
                        onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, hra: e.target.value })}
                        placeholder='HRA' />
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' id='fixedAllowance'
                        onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, fixedAllowance: e.target.value })}
                        placeholder='Fixed Allowance' />
                    
                     <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
)
 }
```

```
        export default PayrollHr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify function, which you are using for handling onChange event to modify more fields than one. For example if you want to change monthly and basic based on annual field you can use something like this:

```
<input
    type='text'
    className='form-control'
    id='annual'
    onChange={(e) => {
      const annual = e.target.value;
      const monthly = annual / 12;
      const basic = (monthly / 100) * 50;

      setPayroll({
        ...payroll,
        annual,
        monthly,
        basic
      })
    }
    placeholder='Annual'
/>
```

Then in other input fields you just need to set correct value prop. Just like you already have in monthly input

```
<input
  type='text'
  className='form-control'
  id='monthly'
  value={payroll.monthly}
  placeholder='Monthly'
/>
```

I would also consider disabling those fields since their value is set based on annual.

Comment: thnx it worked. and i provided defaultValue instead of value in input field and then it saved in mongodb database also

Comment: but there is one problem after submitting form page is not refreshing and value still there in input

Comment: Page is not refreshing because you are using e.preventDefault() in your submit handler function. To reset a form you would have to reset a payroll object in a state after submitting a form

Answer (score 0):

you can use useRef for this and refer tha one value into other value. It could help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).